# Imagick() return null without any error

Tags: imagick

I tried to apply @orrd's code from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14989870/616559). However when I point `Imagick()` to an image, I receive a `null` object without any errors.

I have successfully installed the `Imagick` extension on my server and added `extension=extension=imagick.so` to `php.ini` file.