# How to detect EXIF orientation and rotate image using ImageMagick in custom CMS config file?

Tags: rotation, orientation, imagick, exif

How to add rotate function in my config file, cannot understand, where to add and how, my code is here. This code from cms, its working, need to detect exif and add autorotate function, if image orientation wrong:

```html
# ImageMagick
   
    private function saveFileIM()
    {
        if($this->imShell) {
            $filename_orig = escapeshellarg($this->img['orig_filename']);
            $filename_dest = escapeshellarg($this->img['filename']);
        }
        
        do{
        
        // crop по указанным координатам и размерам
        if( ! empty($this->img['crop_width']) || ! empty($this->img['crop_height'])) {
            if($this->imShell) {
                // not implemented   
            } else {
                $this->im->cropImage($this->img['orig_width'], $this->img['orig_height'], $this->img['src_x'], $this->img['src_y']);
            }
        }
            
        // если пропорции будут сохранятся
        if($this->img['autofit'])
        {
            // указаны значения и высоты и ширины, обрезать изображение точно по размерам
            if( $this->img['height']<=0 && $this->img['width']<=0 ) {
                $this->error('no_th_size');
                break;
            }
            
            if($this->imShell)
            {
                if( ! $this->img['height'])
                {
                    // не указана высота thumbnail'a пропорциональное изображение по ширине
                    if(exec($this->imPath.'convert '.$filename_orig.' 
                            -resize '.$this->img['width'].'x
                            -quality '.$this->img['quality'].' '.$filename_dest))
                        $this->error('im_prop_w_err');
                }
                else if( ! $this->img['width'])
                {
                    // не указана ширина thumbnail'a пропорциональное изображение по высоте
                    if(exec($this->imPath.'convert '.$filename_orig.' 
                            -resize x'.$this->img['height'].'
                            -quality '.$this->img['quality'].' '.$filename_dest))
                        $this->error('im_prop_h_err');
                }         
                else
                {
                    if( $this->img['autofit_nocrop'] ) {
                        // not implemented
                    }

                    // проверяем какая сторона ужимается меньше всего
                    $nWidthDif = $this->img['width'] / $this->img['orig_width'];
                    $nHeightDif = $this->img['height'] / $this->img['orig_height'];
                    // сжимаем пропорционально по ширине или по высоте (по меньшему сжатию) сторону, коэф сжатия которой больше обрезаем
                    if($nWidthDif > $nHeightDif)
                    {
                        $this->cropHeight($nWidthDif, $this->img['crop_v']);
                        if(exec($this->imPath.'convert '.$filename_orig.' 
                                -resize '.$this->img['width'].'x
                                -quality '.$this->img['quality'].' '.$filename_dest))
                           $this->error('im_prop_h_err'); 
                    }
                    else                        
                    {
                        $this->cropWidth($nHeightDif, $this->img['crop_h']);
                        if(exec($this->imPath.'convert '.$filename_orig.' 
                                -resize x'.$this->img['height'].'
                                -quality '.$this->img['quality'].' '.$filename_dest))
                            $this->error('im_prop_w_err');
                    }
                    
                    // обрезка изображения до точного размера
                    if(exec($this->imPath.'convert '.$filename_dest.' 
                                -gravity '.$this->img['gravity'].'
                                -quality 100 
                                -crop '.$this->img['width'].'x'.$this->img['height'].'+0+0 +repage
                                '.$filename_dest))
                        $this->error('im_croping_err');
                }
            } else {
                if( ! $this->img['height']) {
                    if( !$this->im->thumbnailImage($this->img['width'], 0) )
                            $this->error('im_prop_w_err');
                } else if( ! $this->img['width']) {
                    if( ! $this->im->thumbnailImage(0, $this->img['height']) )
                            $this->error('im_prop_h_err');
                } else {
                    if( $this->img['autofit_nocrop'] )
                    {
                        if( ! empty($this->img['autofit_nocrop_bg'])) {
                            $bg_clr = $this->img['autofit_nocrop_bg']; // формат: 0xFFFFFF
                            //
                        }
                        if( ! $this->im->thumbnailImage($this->img['width'], $this->img['height'], true) )
                            $this->error('im_croping_err');
                    } else {
                        // фиксированной ширины и высоты, только center-center
                        if( ! $this->im->cropThumbnailImage($this->img['width'], $this->img['height']) )
                            $this->error('im_croping_err');
                        $this->im->setImagePage(0, 0, 0, 0); // фикс для gif
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // ужимать не сохраняя пропорции
        else 
        {
            if($this->imShell)
            {
                if( ! $this->img['height'] && $this->img['width']>0)
                {
                  /* не указана высота  thumbnaila (выставляем высоту оригинального изображения) */  
                  if(exec($this->imPath.'convert '.$filename_orig.' 
                        -scale '.$this->img['width'].'x'.$this->img['orig_height'].'!
                        -quality '.$this->img['quality'].' '.$filename_dest))
                    $this->error('im_unprop_h_err'); 
                }                              
                else if( ! $this->img['width']&& $this->img['height']>0)
                {
                  /* не указана ширина thumbnaila (выставляем ширину оригинального изображения) */     
                  if(exec($this->imPath.'convert '.$filename_orig.'
                        -scale '.$this->img['orig_width'].'x'.$this->img['height'].'!
                        -quality '.$this->img['quality'].' '.$filename_dest))
                    $this->error('im_unprop_w_err');
                }                               
                else{
                  if(exec($this->imPath.'convert '.$filename_orig.' 
                        -scale '.$this->img['width'].'x'.$this->img['height'].'!
                        -quality '.$this->img['quality'].' '.$filename_dest))
                     $this->error('im_unprop_err');   
                }
            } else {
                if( ! $this->im->thumbnailImage($this->img['width'], $this->img['height']) )
                    $this->error('im_unprop_err'); 
            }
        } 
        
        } while(false);
                                           
        // нанесение watermark
        if($this->img['watermark'] && $this->img['watermark_src'])
        {
           $this->watermarkPrintIM();
        }
        
        // закругление углов
        if($this->img['round_corners'])
        {
            $this->roundCornersIM($this->img['filename'], $this->img['round_corners_color'], $this->img['round_corners_radius'], $this->img['round_corners_rate']);
        }

        if( ! $this->imShell) {
            $this->im->writeImage($this->img['filename']);
        }
        
        $this->clearOriginalImage();
     }
     
    /**
     * Приводим положение картинки к формату ImageMagick
     * @param mixed $vertical - положение по вертикали
     * @param mixed $horizontal - положение по горизонтали
     * @param mixed $pos
     */
    private function convertDimentionsIM($vertical, $horizontal, $pos = false)
    {
         if( ! empty($pos))
         {
             $i_w = $pos['i_w'];
             $i_h = $pos['i_h'];
             $t_w = $pos['t_w'];
             $t_h = $pos['t_h'];
             $paddingV = $pos['p_v'];
             $paddingH = $pos['p_h'];
             
             $x_right  = $i_w - $t_w - $paddingH;
             $x_center = round(($i_w - $t_w)/2);
             $y_center = round(($i_h - $t_h)/2);
             $y_bottom = $i_h - $t_h - $paddingV;
             
             $gravity = array(           
                'top-left'      => array($paddingH, $paddingV), // x - horizontal, y- vertical             
                'top-center'    => array($x_center, $paddingV),
                'top-right'     => array($x_right,  $paddingV),
                'center-left'   => array($paddingH, $y_center),
                'center-center' => array($x_center, $y_center),
                'center-right'  => array($x_right,  $y_center),
                'bottom-left'   => array($paddingH, $y_bottom),
                'bottom-center' => array($x_center, $y_bottom),
                'bottom-right'  => array($x_right,  $y_bottom),
             );
             return $gravity[$vertical.'-'.$horizontal];
         } else {
             $gravity = array(
                'top-left'      => array('NorthWest', IMagick::GRAVITY_NORTHWEST),
                'top-center'    => array('North',     IMagick::GRAVITY_NORTH),
                'top-right'     => array('NorthEast', IMagick::GRAVITY_NORTHEAST),
                'center-left'   => array('West',      IMagick::GRAVITY_WEST),
                'center-center' => array('Center',    IMagick::GRAVITY_CENTER),
                'center-right'  => array('East',      IMagick::GRAVITY_EAST),
                'bottom-left'   => array('SouthWest', IMagick::GRAVITY_SOUTHWEST),
                'bottom-center' => array('South',     IMagick::GRAVITY_SOUTH),
                'bottom-right'  => array('SouthEast', IMagick::GRAVITY_SOUTHEAST),
             );
             return $gravity[$vertical.'-'.$horizontal][ ($this->imShell ? 0 : 1) ];
         }
     }

    /**
     * Наносим watermark нa изображение с помощью Image Magick
     */
    private function watermarkPrintIM()
    {
        $sGravity = $this->convertDimentionsIM($this->img['watermark_pos_y'], $this->img['watermark_pos_x']);

        $sTmpWatermarkFile = $this->imTmpPath.'def_w_mark.png';
        
        // на основе изображения
        if(file_exists($this->img['watermark_src']))
        {
            /** 
             * если указано что wm надо ужимать вместе с картинкой
             * то получаем размеры загружаемого wm
             * и уменьшаем его пропорционально с основным изображением
             */
            if($this->imShell)
            {
                if($this->img['watermark_resizable'])
                {
                    $sParam = exec($this->imPath.'identify '.$this->img['watermark_src']);
                    $aParam = split(' ', $sParam);
                    $aSize  = split('x',$aParam[2]);
                    $nWMwidth  = intval($aSize[0] * $this->img['coef_width']);
                    $nWMheight = intval($aSize[1] * $this->img['coef_height']);
                    if( exec($this->imPath.'convert '.$this->img['watermark_src'].' -scale '.$nWMwidth.'x'.$nWMheight.' -quality '.$this->img['quality'].' '.$sTmpWatermarkFile) )
                        $this->error('im_wmresize_err');
                }
                
                // накладываем wm на thumbnail
                if( exec($this->imPath.'composite -dissolve 100 -gravity '.$sGravity.' -geometry +'.$this->img['watermark_padding_h'].'+'.$this->img['watermark_padding_v'].' '.$sTmpWatermarkFile.' '. $this->img['filename'].' '.$this->img['filename']) )
                    $this->error('im_wmadd_err');
                
                // накладываем wm на оригинал
                if($this->img['watermark_on_original'])
                {
                   if(exec($this->imPath.'composite -dissolve 100 -gravity '.$sGravity.' -geometry +'.$this->img['watermark_padding_h'].'+'.$this->img['watermark_padding_v'].' '. $this->img['watermark_src'] .' '. $this->img['orig_filename'].' '.$this->img['orig_filename']))
                        $this->error('im_wmorig_err');
                }
            } 
            else 
            {
                $wm = new Imagick($this->img['watermark_src']);
                $wmSize = array($wm->getImageWidth(), $wm->getImageHeight());
                if($this->img['watermark_resizable']) {
                    $wmSize[0] = intval($wmSize[0] * $this->img['coef_width']);  //width
                    $wmSize[1] = intval($wmSize[1] * $this->img['coef_height']); //height
                    $wm->thumbnailImage( $wmSize[1], $wmSize[0] );
                }

                // накладываем wm на thumbnail
                $aGravity = $this->convertDimentionsIM($this->img['watermark_pos_y'], $this->img['watermark_pos_x'],
                            array('t_w'=>$wmSize[0],'t_h'=>$wmSize[1],
                                  'i_w'=>$this->im->getImageWidth(),'i_h'=>$this->im->getImageHeight(),
                                  'p_v'=>$this->img['watermark_padding_v'], 'p_h'=>$this->img['watermark_padding_h']));
                
                // накладывает watermark на thumbnail
                if( ! $this->im->compositeImage( $wm, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, $aGravity[0], $aGravity[1] ) )
                    $this->error('im_wmadd_err'); 
                
                // накладываем wm на оригинал
                if($this->img['watermark_on_original'])
                {                   
                   $imSrc = new Imagick($this->img['orig_filename']);
                   
                   $aGravitySrc = $this->convertDimentionsIM($this->img['watermark_pos_y'], $this->img['watermark_pos_x'],
                                array('t_w'=>$wmSize[0],'t_h'=>$wmSize[1],
                                      'i_w'=>$imSrc->getImageWidth(),'i_h'=>$imSrc->getImageHeight(),
                                      'p_v'=>$this->img['watermark_padding_v'], 'p_h'=>$this->img['watermark_padding_h']));

                   if( ! $imSrc->compositeImage( $wm, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, $aGravitySrc[0], $aGravitySrc[1] ) )
                        $this->error('im_wmorig_err');                     
                   else {
                       $imSrc->writeImage( $this->img['orig_filename'] );
                   }
                   $imSrc->destroy();   
                } 
                
                $wm->destroy();            
            }
        }
        else // на основе текста
        {
            //задаем цвет шрифта wm в формате #ffffff
            $sText      = $this->img['watermark_src'];
            $sTextColor = $this->img['watermark_font_color'];
            $sFont      = $this->sFontDir.'/'.$this->img['watermark_font'];
            $nFontSize  = $this->img['watermark_font_size'];
            $nCoef = 1;
            if($this->img['watermark_resizable']) {
                // размер шрифта уменьшается пропорционально картинке
                $nCoef = ($this->img['coef_width']>$this->img['coef_height'] ? $this->img['coef_height'] : $this->img['coef_width']);
                $nFontSize = round($nCoef * $nFontSize);
            }

            if($this->imShell) 
            {       
                // создает изображение png из текста переданного как wm (размер шрифта не изменяется)
                if(exec($this->imPath.'convert -background "none"  -fill "'.$sTextColor.'" -font '.$sFont.' -pointsize '.($nFontSize).' label:"'.addslashes($sText).'" '.$sTmpWatermarkFile)) 
                    $this->error('im_wmorig_err'); 
                
                // накладывает watermark на thumbnail
                if(exec($this->imPath.'composite -dissolve 100 -gravity '.$sGravity.' -geometry +'.($this->img['watermark_padding_h'] * $nCoef).'+'.$this->img['watermark_padding_v']*$nCoef.' '.$sTmpWatermarkFile.' '.$this->img['filename'] .' '.$this->img['filename']))
                    $this->error('im_wmcreate_err');   

                // накладывает watermark на оригинал изображения
                if($this->img['watermark_on_original']) {
                   if(exec($this->imPath.'composite -dissolve 100 -gravity '.$sGravity.' -geometry +'.$this->img['watermark_padding_h'].'+'.$this->img['watermark_padding_v'].' '.$sTmpWatermarkFile.' '. $this->img['orig_filename'].' '.$this->img['orig_filename']))
                        $this->error('im_wmorig_err');
                }
            } 
            else 
            {
                $wmText = new ImagickDraw();
                $wmText->setGravity( IMagick::GRAVITY_CENTER );
                $wmText->setFont( $sFont );
                $wmText->setFontSize( $nFontSize );
                $wmText->setFillColor( $sTextColor ); 
                
                $wm = new Imagick();
                $wmTextProps = $wm->queryFontMetrics( $wmText, $sText );
                $wmW = intval( $wmTextProps['textWidth'] );
                $wmH = intval( $wmTextProps['textHeight'] );
                $wm->newImage( $wmW, $wmH, new ImagickPixel( 'transparent' ), 'png' );
                $wm->setImageVirtualPixelMethod(Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_TRANSPARENT);
                $wm->annotateImage( $wmText, 0, 0, 0, $sText );
                
                $aGravity = $this->convertDimentionsIM($this->img['watermark_pos_y'], $this->img['watermark_pos_x'],
                            array('t_w'=>$wmW,'t_h'=>$wmH,
                                  'i_w'=>$this->im->getImageWidth(),'i_h'=>$this->im->getImageHeight(),
                                  'p_v'=>$this->img['watermark_padding_v'], 'p_h'=>$this->img['watermark_padding_h']));
                
                // накладывает watermark на thumbnail
                //$this->im->annotateImage( $wmText, $aGravity[0], $aGravity[1], 0, $sText );
                
                if( ! $this->im->compositeImage( $wm, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, $aGravity[0], $aGravity[1] ) )
                    $this->error('im_wmcreate_err');   

                // накладывает watermark на оригинал изображения
                if($this->img['watermark_on_original'])
                {
                   $imSrc = new Imagick($this->img['orig_filename']);
                   
                   $aGravitySrc = $this->convertDimentionsIM($this->img['watermark_pos_y'], $this->img['watermark_pos_x'],
                                array('t_w'=>$wmW,'t_h'=>$wmH,
                                      'i_w'=>$imSrc->getImageWidth(),'i_h'=>$imSrc->getImageHeight(),
                                      'p_v'=>$this->img['watermark_padding_v'], 'p_h'=>$this->img['watermark_padding_h'] ));

                   if( ! $imSrc->compositeImage( $wm, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, $aGravitySrc[0], $aGravitySrc[1] ) )
                        $this->error('im_wmorig_err'); 
                   else {
                       $imSrc->writeImage( $this->img['orig_filename'] );
                   }
                   $imSrc->destroy();
                }
                
                $wmText->destroy();
                $wm->destroy();
            }
        }
            
        // удаление временного файла с wm
        $this->img['orig_filename'] = $this->img['src'];
        if(file_exists($sTmpWatermarkFile)) {
            unlink($sTmpWatermarkFile);
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Создание закругленных уголков с помощью Image Magick
     */ 
    private function roundCornersIM($filename, $cornercolor, $radius=5, $rate=5)
    {   
        // Если png/gif тогда углы прозрачные
        if($this->img['format'] == IMAGETYPE_GIF || $this->img['format'] == IMAGETYPE_PNG) {
            $cornercolor = false;
        }
        
        if($radius<=0) return false;
        if($radius > 100) $radius = 100;
        if($rate <=0) $rate = 5;
        else if($rate > 20) $rate = 20;
                
        $width  = $this->img['width'];
        $height = $this->img['height'];
        $radius = ($width<=$height)?((($width/100)*$radius)/2):((($height/100)*$radius)/2); 

        if($cornercolor === false)
        {
            $sOldName = $filename;
            $sNewName = $filename;
            if($this->img['format']!==IMAGETYPE_PNG) {
                $nLength  = strrpos($filename,'.');
                $sNewName = substr($filename,0,$nLength).'.png';
            }
            
            if($this->imShell)
            {
                // если углы прозрачные закругляем уголки без заливки цветом
                $cornercolor = 'transparent';
                if(exec($this->imPath.'convert "'.$sOldName.'" -border 0 -format "roundrectangle 0,0 %[fx:w],%[fx:h] '.$radius.','.$radius.'" info: > '.$this->imTmpPath.'tmp.mvg'))
                    $this->error('no_rouncorners');
                if(exec($this->imPath.'convert  "'.$sOldName.'" -border 0 -matte -channel RGBA -threshold -1 -background '.$cornercolor.' -fill none  -strokewidth 0 -draw "@'.$this->imTmpPath.'tmp.mvg"  '.$this->imTmpPath.'__overlay.png'))
                    $this->error('no_rouncorners');
                if(exec($this->imPath.'convert "'.$sOldName.'" -border 0 -matte -channel RGBA -threshold -1 -background '.$cornercolor.' -fill white  -strokewidth 0 -draw "@'.$this->imTmpPath.'tmp.mvg" '.$this->imTmpPath.'__mask.png '))
                    $this->error('no_rouncorners');
                 
                if(exec($this->imPath.'convert "'.$sOldName.'" -matte -bordercolor '.$cornercolor.'  -border 0 '.$this->imTmpPath.'__mask.png -compose DstIn -composite '.$this->imTmpPath.'__overlay.png -compose Over -composite  -quality 95 "'.$sNewName.'"  '))
                    $this->error('no_rouncorners');
                 
                if($sOldName != $sNewName) {
                    unlink($sOldName);
                    rename($sNewName, $sOldName);
                }   
                unlink($this->imTmpPath.'__mask.png'); 
                unlink($this->imTmpPath.'__overlay.png'); 
            } else {         
                $this->im->setImageFormat('png');
                $this->im->roundCorners($radius, $radius);
            }
        } 
        else
        {
            if($this->imShell)
            {
                // если углы не прозрачные закругляем уголки и заливаем из выставленным цветом 
                if(exec($this->imPath.'convert "'.$filename.'"  -border 0 -format "fill '.$cornercolor.' rectangle 0,0 %[fx:w],%[fx:h]" info: > '.$this->imTmpPath.'tmp.mvg'))
                    $this->error('no_rouncorners'); 
                if(exec( $this->imPath.'convert "'.$filename.'" -matte -channel RGBA -threshold -1 -draw "@'.$this->imTmpPath.'tmp.mvg" PNG:'.$this->imTmpPath.'__underlay.png'))
                   $this->error('no_rouncorners');
                if(exec($this->imPath.'convert '.$this->imTmpPath.'__underlay.png ( "'.$filename.'" ( +clone -threshold -1 -draw "fill black polygon 0,0 0,'.$radius.' '.$radius.',0 fill white circle '.$radius.','.$radius.' '.$radius.',0" ( +clone -flip ) -compose Multiply -composite ( +clone -flop ) -compose Multiply -composite -blur 1x1 ) +matte -compose CopyOpacity -composite ) -matte -compose over -composite "'.$filename.'"'))
                    $this->error('no_rouncorners');
                
                unlink($this->imTmpPath.'__underlay.png');
            } else {
                $this->im->setImageFormat('png');
                $this->im->roundCorners($radius, $radius);
//                $bg = new Imagick();
//                $bg->newImage($this->im->getImageWidth(), $this->im->getImageHeight(), new ImagickPixel($cornercolor));
//                $bg->compositeImage($this->im, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0);
//                $this->im->setImage($bg);
            }
        }
        
        if(file_exists($this->imTmpPath.'tmp.mvg')) {
            unlink($this->imTmpPath.'tmp.mvg'); 
        }
        
        $this->img['orig_filename'] = $this->img['src'];
        
        return $this->errors->no();
     }

    public function getErrors()
    {
        return $this->errors->show();
    }
           
    /**
    * Устанавливает лимит оперативной памяти
    * @param int $nSize - объем памяти в мегабайтах
    */
    public function setMemoryLimit($nSize)
    {
        $nSize = intval($nSize);
        if($nSize<=0) $nSize=1;
        ini_set('memory_limit', $nSize.'M');
    }

    /**
    * Указание пути к шрифтам
    * @param string путь к директории c файлами шрифтов
    */
    function setFontDir($sPath)
    {
        $this->sFontDir = $sPath;
    }

    function getAutofitResultSize($nWidth = false, $nHeight = false)
    {
        if( ! $nHeight) # не указана высота, возвращаем autofit-высоту
        {
          return intval( ($nWidth/$this->img['orig_width'])*$this->img['orig_height'] );
        }
        else if( ! $nWidth) # не указана ширина, возвращаем autofit-ширину
        {
          return intval( ($nHeight/$this->img['orig_height'])*$this->img['orig_width'] );
        }         
    }

    function getOriginalWidth()
    {
        return (int)$this->img['src_width'];
    }

    function getOriginalHeight()
    {
        return (int)$this->img['src_height'];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the reply from @orrd in this thread: [How to stop PHP iMagick auto-rotating images based on EXIF 'orientation' data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266656/how-to-stop-php-imagick-auto-rotating-images-based-on-exif-orientation-data)

You will have to work out where to put it as I am not keen on working through over 500 lines of somebody else's code.

You may still have problems if the orientation data is missing or incorrect.

Comment: thank you for your answere, but i cannot uderstand, what variables to use for my code $image = new Imagick('my-image-file.jpg');
autoRotateImage($image);
// - Do other stuff to the image here -
$image->writeImage('result-image.jpg');