# Photo is rotated on upload. PHP ImageMagick

Tags: php, imagemagick

the photo before loading in the preview is correct, but on the server it is already saved sideways

Image save code:

```
public function postUploadImage($path, $id) {
        $img = new Imagick($path);
        $profiles = $img->getImageProfiles("icc", true);
        $img->stripImage();
        if(!empty($profiles))
            $img->profileImage("icc", $profiles['icc']);
        $img->cropThumbnailImage(500, 500);
        $img->setImageCompressionQuality(80);
        $img->writeImage($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']  . '/public/materials/'.$id.'.jpg');
        $img->clear();
    }
```

I kind of understand that the problem is EXIF, but how to get rid of them if `stripImage ()` does not work

Thanks for wathing!

If i try used `var_dump(exif_read_data($path));` he return

```
array(7) {
  ["FileName"]=>
  string(9) "phpv0IOKS"
  ["FileDateTime"]=>
  int(1615462769)
  ["FileSize"]=>
  int(99279)
  ["FileType"]=>
  int(2)
  ["MimeType"]=>
  string(10) "image/jpeg"
  ["SectionsFound"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["COMPUTED"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["html"]=>
    string(24) "width="960" height="540""
    ["Height"]=>
    int(540)
    ["Width"]=>
    int(960)
    ["IsColor"]=>
    int(1)
  }
}
```

Comment: is this, by any chance, when using an iPhone?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop PHP iMagick auto-rotating images based on EXIF 'orientation' data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266656/how-to-stop-php-imagick-auto-rotating-images-based-on-exif-orientation-data)

Comment: No, used Samsung, but if i upload with Xiaomi the same images are fine. Very strange

Comment: @Monnomcjo No. I tried all variants ;(

Comment: @Monnomcjo I appended result exif_read_data